# Laravel Download File in Controller but Still Return a View

Tags: laravel, download

I want to download a file from a Laravel Controller but still return a view. How can I achieve something like this?

```
// This is a method from controller accessible by http://localhost/view-download
public function index()
{
     $fileUrl = 'https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/addresses.csv';

     // TODO: code for downloading the CSV file

     return view('views.download');
}
```

I have tried `header()` but it seems after the `header()` codes, the execution stops thus the `return view()` is not executed. I have also tried passing the `$fileUrl` to the blade but downloading the CSV file in the frontend/blade using JS will have long and complicated codes.